# Sort a paginated array

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting, ng-bootstrap

I have a paginated array and I have to sort by columns but when I sort from the current page I get the begenning or the end of the sorted array but if I change the page I get the right sorted values. It seems the current page becomes the 1st page when I trigger the function.

I use the pagination from [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/overview)

Function triggered when I click on a column

```
 sort() {
    if (this.sortAsc == false) {
      this.service.getSortedData().subscribe((data) => {
        this.array = data['data'];
        this.nextPage = data['next_page_url'];
        this.collectionSize = data['total'];
      });
    } else {
      this.service.getSortedDataDesc().subscribe((data) => {
        this.array = data['data'];
        this.nextPage = data['next_page_url'];
        this.collectionSize = data['total'];
      });
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
 <th scope="col" (click)="sort()">
              <fa-icon *ngIf="sortAsc == true" [icon]="faChevronUp"></fa-icon>
              <fa-icon *ngIf="sortAsc == false" [icon]="faChevronDown"></fa-icon>
              Values
            </th>
```

current result with order by desc example:

on click column from page 2 :

```
1000
150
20
```

navigate to sorted page 1 :

```
1000
150
20
```

expected result :

on click column from page 2 :

```
10
6
5
```

navigate to sorted page 1 :

```
1000
150
20
```

data content for page 2:

```
{
current_page: 1
data: (30) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
first_page_url: "http://localhost:8000/api/values?page=1"
from: 1
last_page: 4
last_page_url: "http://localhost:8000/api/values?page=4"
links: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
next_page_url: "http://localhost:8000/api/values?page=2"
path: "http://localhost:8000/api/values"
per_page: 30
prev_page_url: null
to: 30
total: 118
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I don't think this is really clean but it works. I store the current page when I display another page then add a condition in the `sort()` function

```
    sort(){
      if (this.sortAsc == false) {
         this.service.getSortedData().subscribe((data) => {
            this.nextPage = data['next_page_url'];
            this.collectionSize = data['total'];
            if (this.currentPage == 1) {
                this.array = data['data'];
            } else {
              this.service
                .getPage(this.firstPageUrl, this.currentPage)
                .subscribe((data) => {
                         this.array = data['data'];
                });
            }
          });
        } else {
           this.service.getSortedDataDesc().subscribe((data) => {
            this.nextPage = data['next_page_url'];
            this.collectionSize = data['total'];
            if (this.currentPage == 1) {
               this.array = data['data'];
            } else {
              this.service
                .getPage(this.firstPageUrl, this.currentPage)
                .subscribe((data) => {
                         this.array = data['data'];
                });
            }
          });
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you havent provide the cruicial information, I'm guessing that probably the problem is in the `getSortedData()` and `getSortedDataDesc()` functions, what are they returning? You need to offset the data, somehow read current page and subtract those pages from the result passed to

this.array = data['data'];

also, you set the array in the first condition and you're not doing that in the second, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I edited the question, I have an offset. That's what i'm looking for but I don't find the right way

Answer (score 0):

this is because you're subscribing the value changes on a click event. try this instead:

```
  async sort() {
    let data = [];
    if (this.sortAsc == false) {
      data = await this.service.getSortedData().toPromise();
    } else {
      data = await this.service.getSortedDataDesc().toPromise();
    }

    this.array = data['data'];
    this.firstPageUrl = data['first_page_url'];
    this.nextPage = data['next_page_url'];
    this.collectionSize = data['total'];
  }
```

Comment: The same thing happens